# BC30311 error: Why can't I use a PlaceHolder inside a table for a specific user control?

Tags: asp.net, placeholder

We have a standard asp.net web application and have used asp:PlaceHolders in multiple places.  In some files we get this error message during runtime:

> BC30311: Value of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder' cannot
>   be converted to 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow'.

Why?

If I remove the place holder the page renders just fine.

Here is the html (simplified version):

```
<table runat="server" id="tblExtradata" visible=true>               
  <asp:PlaceHolder ID="test" runat="server" Visible="true">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblExpenses" runat="server" Text="Expensesr"></asp:Label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </asp:PlaceHolder>
</table>
```

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5446; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5420

Comment: It turns out that the table never needed to be runat="server".  Why this was added I don't know, as it wasn't used in the code behind, but removing it solved the problem.  (<table> works just fine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're running the table at the server, it expects only table elements nested within. If you take the runat="server out of the table, it should work fine.

Comment: This is correct, as I already wrote in the comment to my question.